# grid line missing in pgfplotstable and doubly printed labels

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplotstable

In the following document, I have been using the same setup for two diagrams.
However, the label "10^1" with its horizontal grid line is only shown in the first diagram.
Obviously, this is due to the data1.dat vs. the data2.dat used.

How can I make sure that the missing grid line is also printed in the second diagram? (It also seems that the y-axis ignores the "ymin=0" key.)

Also, while it is not really visible here, it seems that if a "y tick" would get printed without the  "extra y ticks" key, then this "y tick" (i.e., the label) is printed twice on top of each other.
In another document this label then looks somewhat bold compared to the others.
Maybe I am doing it wrong altogether?

```
\documentclass{article}
% 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{pgf,tikz,pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{data1.dat}
N    V
0    17.3
1    84.4
2    234.6
3    535.8
4    1059.8
5    2406.6
6    2997.6
7    4798.4
8    7356.6
9    10721.6
10    15470.4
11    21714.7
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{data2.dat}
N    V
0    26.3
1    73.4
2    234.3
3    640.9
4    1063.0
5    1888.9
6    3145.6
7    4999.6
8    7671.4
9    11407.5
10    16417.3
11    23390.1
12    32443.8
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    ymode=log,
    width=.8\linewidth,
    xmin=0, xmax=9,
    ymax=25000,
    ymin=0,
    restrict y to domain=-1:25000,
    log basis y=10,
    extra x ticks={0,1,...,9},
    extra y ticks={10,100,1000,10000},
    extra tick style={grid=major},
  xlabel=XLAB,
  ylabel=YLAB]
\addplot[blue,line width=1pt,cycle list] table [x=N, y=V]{data1.dat};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\vspace*{1cm}
\rule{\linewidth}{1cm}
\vspace*{1cm}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    ymode=log,
    width=.8\linewidth,
    xmin=0, xmax=9,
    ymax=25000,
    ymin=0,
    restrict y to domain=-1:25000,
    log basis y=10,
    extra x ticks={0,1,...,9},
    extra y ticks={10,100,1000,10000},
    extra tick style={grid=major},
  xlabel=XLAB,
  ylabel=YLAB]
\addplot[blue,line width=1pt,cycle list] table [x=N, y=V]{data2.dat};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you give the output of your code? It will be better to help us understand your question.

Comment: Did that. Also, it seems that the yaxis ignores the ymin=0 somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I strongly suggest you to see the `warning information` of your code.

### Warning 1

From your code `\usepackage{filecontents}`

```
Package filecontents Warning: This package is obsolete. Disabling it and passing control to the filecontents environment defined by the LaTeX kernel.
```

As warning says, latex kernel has defined the `filecontents` environment, see `latex2e sec 8.11 filecontents: Write an external file`

### Warning 2

From your code `\usepackage{pgf,tikz,pgfplotstable}`

```
Package pgfplots Warning: running in backwards compatibility mode (unsuitable tick labels; missing features). Consider writing \pgfplotsset{compat=1.17} into your preamble.
```

`pgfplots` comes with two components:

- the plotting component
- the pgfplotstable component which simplifies number formatting and postprocessing of numerical tables.

I don't think you need the `pgfplotstable` component. The warning also suggest you to add `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}` to your preamble. In the documentation, the `compat` is strongly suggested to always write to your `.tex` file. Cause

> While this key imposes some work to end-users, it also solves a common requirement: it
> ensures that your .tex files always result in the same output, even if you install a new version of pgfplots.
> On the other hand, it allows us as maintainers to solve software defects and introduce changes in behavior,
> assuming that these changes only affect documents with a decent compatibility level.

Instead of `\usepackage{pgf,tikz,pgfplotstable}`, you just need

```
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
```

### Warning 3

The following two warnings are of the same reason: the combination of `ymode=log` and `ymin=0`

```
Package pgfplots Warning: Ignoring illegal input argument ymin=0: cannot apply log. on input line 58.
```

The reason is simple: `0` is an invalid value to be passed to `log` function.

### Warnin 4

From your code `\rule{\linewidth}{1cm}`

```
Overfull \hbox (15.0pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 64--66
```

You need to add `\noindent` before `\rule{\linewidth}{1cm}`

### Correction

Change `ymin` to a suitable value such as `9`, you will get what you want.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}

\begin{filecontents}{data1.dat}
N    V
0    17.3
1    84.4
2    234.6
3    535.8
4    1059.8
5    2406.6
6    2997.6
7    4798.4
8    7356.6
9    10721.6
10    15470.4
11    21714.7
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{data2.dat}
N    V
0    26.3
1    73.4
2    234.3
3    640.9
4    1063.0
5    1888.9
6    3145.6
7    4999.6
8    7671.4
9    11407.5
10    16417.3
11    23390.1
12    32443.8
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    ymode=log,
    width=.8\linewidth,
    xmin=0, xmax=9,
    ymax=25000,
    ymin=9,
    restrict y to domain=-1:25000,
    log basis y=10,
    extra x ticks={0,1,...,9},
    extra y ticks={10,100,1000,10000},
    extra tick style={grid=major},
  xlabel=XLAB,
  ylabel=YLAB]
\addplot[blue,line width=1pt,cycle list] table [x=N, y=V]{data1.dat};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\vspace*{1cm}
\noindent\rule{\linewidth}{1cm}
\vspace*{1cm}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    ymode=log,
    width=.8\linewidth,
    xmin=0, xmax=9,
    ymax=25000,
    ymin=9,
    restrict y to domain=-1:25000,
    log basis y=10,
    extra x ticks={0,1,...,9},
    extra y ticks={10,100,1000,10000},
    extra tick style={grid=major},
  xlabel=XLAB,
  ylabel=YLAB]
\addplot[blue,line width=1pt,cycle list] table [x=N, y=V]{data2.dat};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks! ymin=9 indeed solves the problem here.

Comment: @RonnieMarksch I do not understand what do you mean `y tick` or `label` is bolder than usual. Maybe you need provide a minimum working example.

Comment: I had the automatic normal ticks and labels. Then I added extra ticks and labels (partly on top of the former ones). In another document the labels then appear to be a little bolder. I fixed this by omitting extra ticks and setting tick distance instead.